# Storing DateTime JPA in Postgresql

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jodatime

Why are the columns being created as type 'bytea' for DateTime in the database? How can I get JPA to create the correct column type for DateTime?

**Entitiy**

```
DateTime expiresAt;
DateTime createdAt;
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes = true
```

**pom.xml**

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.9</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
      <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: OT: If you are on Java 8, suggest you to use java.time.LocalDateTime . Spring Data does supports Java time API.

Comment: I think we should use Timestamp format in the database